# How to read in long list of parameters into GDB/DDD

Tags: linux, bash, unix, gdb

I have written this C++ program which has a fairly lengthy list of parameters which
I supply at the BASH command line.

However for debugging with GDB, it is a pain to type 
`run param1 param2 ....` at the GDB command prompt for debugging my executable.

So is there a way to store this lengthy list into a text file and tell GDB to look at this text file for the parameters  for supplying the arguments to my **a.out**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So is there a way to store this lengthy list into a text file and tell GDB to look at this text file for the parameters for supplying the arguments to my a.out

Put this into the text file:

```
set args foo bar baz ...
```

and then

```
(gdb) source commands.txt
```

Alternatively:

```
gdb --args ./a.out foo bar baz ...
(gdb) run
```